# Plotly add hline to existing legend entry from scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have a scatter plot with two or more different data sets. For each data set I also added a hline of their means.
I would like to link the hline to the legend of the corresponding dataset so that if I deselect a dataset in the legend, the hline disappears as well.

Is this possible in plotly?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2],
                   'y1': [5, 4, 7],
                   'y2': [2, 3, 1]})
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y1'],
    mode='markers',
    name='y1'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y2'],
    mode='markers',
    name='y2'
))

fig.add_hline(y=df['y1'].mean())
fig.add_hline(y=df['y2'].mean())

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it must be graphically supported to be reflected in the legend. So we draw a line using the line mode of the scatter plot. Then, set up a legend group to group the scatter and line graphs. Once this is done, you can show or hide the legend by clicking on it.

The second image is an example of the y2 legend clicked to hide it.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 2],
                   'y1': [5, 4, 7],
                   'y2': [2, 3, 1]})
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y1'],
    mode='markers',
    name='y1',
    legendgroup='1'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y2'],
    mode='markers',
    name='y2',
    legendgroup='2'

))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        mode='lines',
        x=df['x'],
        y=[df['y1'].mean()]*len(df),
        line_color='blue',
        legendgroup='1'
    )
)
             
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        mode='lines',
        x=df['x'],
        y=[df['y2'].mean()]*len(df),
        line_color='red',
        legendgroup='2'
    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it is not possible with add_hline? The line mode of Scatter does not make a line from end to end but rather from first point to last point

Comment: `add_hline()` is not subject to the legend.

Comment: And if you want to draw a line from one end to the other, you can do so by changing the following. `fig.update_xaxes(range=[-0.02,2.02])` or`fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,2])`

Comment: See the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/#adding-to-multiple-facets--subplots) for vertical and horizontal lines.